# Getting exported cache into a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to access a exported Cache into another file, but not having success.

Basically I've got two files:

**cache.ts** *I'll expose only the part that meter*

```
import Cache = require('node-cache');

const narrativeCache: Cache = New Cache();

protected setNarrativeCache(): void {
  narrativeCache.set(123,'abc',0);
}

module.exports.narrativeCache = narrativeCache;
```

I want use this narrative in this other file:

**module.ts**

```
import { narrativeCache } from '../transport/cache.ts';
function test1(): void {
   narrativeCache.get(123); //Error in here, it doesn't find this
}
```

**Files tree:**

- `src\transport\cache.ts`
- `src\reader\module.ts`

The error is because it doesn't find this narrativeCache.

Comment: cause the file is `./cache` ? Also its `module.exports` (with an *s*) and you aren't using the default export, you have to `import { narrativeCache }`

Comment: Sorry, put it wrong, but still getting error

Comment: Can you update your question with latest changes?

Comment: Done!! @iofjuupasli

Comment: It's now getting error because of the import @JonasWilms: "Module '"../../../../../../Projects/Motorola/Repository/file-poller-connector/src/transport"' has no exported member 'narrativeCache'."

Comment: Find what is wrong, it's a typescript error. The solution was exported like that; export const narrativeCache: Cache = new Cache();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was becausing of typescript export type:

Here's the solution

export const narrativeCache: Cache = new Cache();